# What window messages are triggered when window comes to foreground?

Tags: windows, windows-messages

What windows messages are triggered (wm_xyz) when an application window goes from background to foreground (or from invisible/minimized to visible/maximised)?

Comment: Why not put tracing messages in your WndProc?

Comment: It depends on how the window is brought to the front.  Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

There's a complex interaction involving:

- WM_NCHITTEST
- WM_NCACTIVATE
- WM_ACTIVATEAPP
- WM_ACTIVATE
- WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
- WM_SETFOCUS
- WM_SHOWWINDOW
- WM_NCPAINT
- WM_PAINT
- and others, depending on the details of the situation

You can learn a lot by using Spy++ (which comes with Visual Studio).

If you can provide more detail on what you're trying to do, we can probably point you to the right subset of messages.  To learn more about a specific message, search for the message/notification with MSDN, e.g., "MSDN WM_PAINT".